# JWT unauthenticate on Android after few minutes of idle app

Tags: android, node.js, jwt

I have a nodejs server that connects to android client with an express JWT. The property of JWT is `expiresInMinutes: 60*5*100`

But if I leave app idle in background for more than a few seconds, open other apps, and then reopen my app from background, the app does not open properly and server shows a JWT error with following trace

```
error: Server Error:
error: Error
    at /home/ubuntu/marrily-server/marrily-dev/marrily-api/marrily/node_modules/express-jwt/lib/index.js:109:53
    at /home/ubuntu/marrily-server/marrily-dev/marrily-api/marrily/node_modules/jsonwebtoken/index.js:98:18
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:67:7)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:122:9) { Error
    at /home/ubuntu/marrily-server/marrily-dev/marrily-api/marrily/node_modules/express-jwt/lib/index.js:109:53
    at /home/ubuntu/marrily-server/marrily-dev/marrily-api/marrily/node_modules/jsonwebtoken/index.js:98:18
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:67:7)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:122:9)
  name: 'UnauthorizedError',
  message: 'jwt malformed',
  code: 'invalid_token',
  status: 401,
  inner: 
   { Error
       at Object.module.exports.verify (/home/ubuntu/marrily-server/marrily-dev/marrily-api/marrily/node_modules/jsonwebtoken/index.js:115:17)
       at /home/ubuntu/marrily-server/marrily-dev/marrily-api/marrily/node_modules/express-jwt/lib/index.js:108:11
       at /home/ubuntu/marrily-server/marrily-dev/marrily-api/marrily/node_modules/express-jwt/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:251:17
       at done (/home/ubuntu/marrily-server/marrily-dev/marrily-api/marrily/node_modules/express-jwt/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:132:19)
       at /home/ubuntu/marrily-server/marrily-dev/marrily-api/marrily/node_modules/express-jwt/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:32:16
       at /home/ubuntu/marrily-server/marrily-dev/marrily-api/marrily/node_modules/express-jwt/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:248:21
       at /home/ubuntu/marrily-server/marrily-dev/marrily-api/marrily/node_modules/express-jwt/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:572:34
       at DEFAULT_REVOKED_FUNCTION (/home/ubuntu/marrily-server/marrily-dev/marrily-api/marrily/node_modules/express-jwt/lib/index.js:6:61)
       at /home/ubuntu/marrily-server/marrily-dev/marrily-api/marrily/node_modules/express-jwt/lib/index.js:97:9
       at /home/ubuntu/marrily-server/marrily-dev/marrily-api/marrily/node_modules/express-jwt/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:567:21
       at /home/ubuntu/marrily-server/marrily-dev/marrily-api/marrily/node_modules/express-jwt/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:246:17
       at /home/ubuntu/marrily-server/marrily-dev/marrily-api/marrily/node_modules/express-jwt/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:122:13
       at _each (/home/ubuntu/marrily-server/marrily-dev/marrily-api/marrily/node_modules/express-jwt/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:46:13)
       at async.each (/home/ubuntu/marrily-server/marrily-dev/marrily-api/marrily/node_modules/express-jwt/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:121:9)
       at _asyncMap (/home/ubuntu/marrily-server/marrily-dev/marrily-api/marrily/node_modules/express-jwt/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:245:13)
       at Object.map (/home/ubuntu/marrily-server/marrily-dev/marrily-api/marrily/node_modules/express-jwt/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:216:23) name: 'JsonWebTokenError', message: 'jwt malformed' } }
```

How can this thing be resolved?

**EDIT**

The code to issue token is:

```
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

req.body.id = user[0].id;
try{
    var token = jwt.sign(user[0], 'SomeSuperSecret', {expiresInMinutes: 60*5*100});
}catch(err){
    res.json({msg:'jwt error'});
}
```

The code to verify the token is in `config/http.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  http:{
    customMiddleware: function(app){
      app.use(expressJwt({secret: 'SomeSuperSecret'}).unless({path: [
          //list of URLs
      ]}));
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: you are using a non-standard field `expiresInMinutes`. How are you validating this field in server side. Show the code

Comment: `req.body.id = user[0].id;
     try{
      var token = jwt.sign(user[0], 'someSuperSecret', {expiresInMinutes: 60*5*100});
     }catch(err){
      res.json({msg:'jwt error'});
     }`

Comment: I asked about the code to verify the token. What library are you using? Please include the code editing your question, not int comments. Do you have checked that the JWT is properly sent by your android app?

Comment: Done! I have added them.